# Pourquoi les Français déforment autant les titres de films en les traduisant ?

Tags: traduction, cinéma, titres

Les traductions de titres en français de France font parfois preuve d'imagination d'une liberté que je ne comprends pas toujours.
On peut comparer avec les traductions des titres traduits en français du Canada, qui elles restent plus littérales et proche de l'idée originale.
Des fois on peut même déceler une ombre de spoil, qui n'est pas présent dans le titre original, dans la traduction.

Parfois, les français remplacent par un autre titre anglais, parfois gardent le titre anglais original.

Je me demande donc comment cela est décidé.

En vrac, je pense par exemple à :

Lock, Stock and Two Smoking Barrels, traduit par **Arnaque, Crimes et Botanique**

The Hangover *(i.e. La Gueule de Bois)*, traduit par **Very Bad Trip**

Kill Bill *(i.e. Tuer Bill)*, reste **Kill Bill**

Comment: Similar questions: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14475/reasons-for-difference-in-translation-of-pirates-of-the-caribbean-from-quebec-to, http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6466/why-very-bad-trip-instead-of-gueule-de-bois

Comment: Even when only one language is involved (^^but see below^^), this phenomenon is noticeable at times by comparing **English book** titles with the titles of the **English movies** that were based on those books. [Here are some examples of this](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/book-movie-titles-changing/) & an explanation for each one. ^^I find the discussion under *PLEIN SOLEIL* (near the bottom) especially interesting (& slightly relevant to your question) for it describes an unusual relationship between English and French movie titles where the roles have been curiously reversed.

Comment: Les Américains ne changent pas seulement le titre des films français: ils changent le film entier, par exemple: [Three Men and a Baby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Men_and_a_Baby)

Comment: Ici (au Vietnam), ils changent aussi le titre des films.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'est de la mercatique !

Qu'on se le dise les Français ne sont pas très doués en anglais, mais ils reconnaissent tout de même de nombreux mots. Par exemple dans Kill Bill : kill est mot quasi connu de tous, il n'est donc pas nécessaire de le traduire, et les mots anglais ont la cote en France donc Kill Bill pour un Français ça annonce un bon film américain.

En revanche pour "The Hangover", c'est assez simple : le mot est beaucoup moins connu, alors que tous les mots de "Very bad trip" le sont; de plus, comme dit précédemment, un titre en anglais est plus vendeur en France.

Une autre explication est aussi que les Français aiment bien prononcer les œuvres dans la langue d'origine, si possible (phénomène de mercatique plutôt récent, ceci correspond également à la mentalité des Français puisque c'est plus vendeur).
Les Québécois ont besoin de marquer leurs différences avec le Canada anglophone, à tel point qu'ils défendent la langue française à tout prix : ils finissent par tout traduire même si, lors d'un dialogue informel, les Québécois utilisent (dans la vie de tous les jours) bien plus de mots anglais que les Français.

Answer (score 2):

Two things :

If the film is American and happening in America, it is common practice to signal it by "sounding American".

If the words are slightly less known than the bare minimum, most people won't understand it, so it has to be changed. Sometimes it's translated, sometimes they come up with different English words like for Very Bad Trip ("bad trip" is a well known expression in French). So for example, a film named "Dr. Ruthless" would need its title to be translated or changed, but "Dr. Bad" could stay as is.

It's mostly marketing, and yes many people find this stupid when they learn about it.